# Epoch time confusion, clarification needed

Tags: java, epoch

Given:

```
private Calendar calendarInstance = Calendar.getInstance();

public long inMillis() {
    calendarInstance.set(year, month, day, hour, min);
    return calendarInstance.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

As i understand it, the result comes back with time since the epoch, in milliseconds

> The current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch.

Given that my test always sets the objects the same, why are results coming up different as time goes by?

```
detailedMoment = new MomentInTime(2012, 11, 1, 19, 9);
detailedMoment.inMillis() // gives different results as time passes by
```

**UPDATE:**

I continue to second guess myself due to 
[image]

For the same time period i get

```
1_351_796_940 // http://www.epochconverter.com
1_354_410_540 // my number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [clear()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#clear%28%29). If you do that it will return you the exact number of miliseconds each time.

```
public long inMillis() {
    calendarInstance.clear();
    calendarInstance.set(year, month, day, hour, min);
    return calendarInstance.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

From Java doc

> Sets all the calendar field values and the time value `(millisecond offset from the Epoch)` of this Calendar undefined. This means that isSet() will return false for all the calendar fields, and the date and time calculations will treat the fields as if they had never been set. A Calendar implementation class may use its specific default field values for date/time calculations. For example, GregorianCalendar uses `1970` if the YEAR field value is undefined.

A Sample program

```
public class MomentInTime {

private static Calendar calendarInstance = Calendar.getInstance();

public static long inMillis() {
    calendarInstance.clear();
    calendarInstance.set(2012, 10, 1, 19, 9);
    return calendarInstance.getTimeInMillis();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(inMillis()/1000);
        Thread.sleep(300);
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
 1351777140
```

[image]

Comment: @Jam I checked it and I get consistent results with It.I even converted to Date and checked it returns appropriate value.

Comment: My numbers seem to disagree with http://www.epochconverter.com. What do you get when getting time in milliseconds on date above

Comment: @Jam Added a Sample you can check the out put it is same for that day though there is sleep and time is changing.

Comment: Thank you. You're absolutely right. Can you please glance above and help explain possible number discrepancy.

Comment: @Jam Problem might be because you are not specifying time zone and converting to GMT. Check with Local time zone. My values match exactly. You have to create calendar instance using Timezone GMT to match with GMT

Comment: Thank you again Amit for your time, example and thorough explanation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18941/discussion-between-jam-and-amitd)

Answer (score 2):

Well you don't set the seconds or milliseconds.
[JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) says:

> Sets the year, month, day of the month, hour of day and minute fields.
>   **Other fields are not changed.**

Answer (score 1):

I guess that is because you are missing **seconds** and **milliseconds** of the Calendar.getInstance().

You are just replacing `year, month, day, hour, min` of Calendar object, but every time when you get calendar instance, seconds and milliseconds of that particular point in time may change.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Test
        System.out.println(inMillis(2021,6,19,8,30));
    }
    public static long inMillis(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int min) {
        return LocalDate.now()
                .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                .withYear(year)
                .withMonth(month)
                .withDayOfMonth(day)
                .withHour(hour)
                .withMinute(min)
                .toInstant()
                .toEpochMilli();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1624091400000
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/HQ0ZkG)

**This is how http://www.epochconverter.com displays it:**

[image]

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### Update:

**A simpler version** (thanks to Ole V.V.):

```
public static long inMillis(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int min) {
    return OffsetDateTime.of(year, month, day, hour, min, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toInstant()
            .toEpochMilli();
}
```

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Thanks for showing the modern solution that is definitely recommended these days. Would `OffsetDateTime.of(2012, 11, 1, 19, 9, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli()` seem simpler? (yields 1 351 796 940 000, which seems to agree with the asker’s expectations.)